# How do I set a custom colourbar for unequal data ranges in matlab?

Tags: matlab, colorbar

I have some shelf sea data and need to plot values equal to NaN in one colour (for the land), values less than 2.7 in another colour, and values above 2.7 in a third colour. I've tried creating a custom colourbar with three colours (blue for 0, aqua for 0.001 to 2.7 and yellow for everything else), however, it plots a colour bar that has 3 equal sections (blue for 0 - 2, aqua for 2 - 4 and yellow for 4 - 6). I'm very new to Matlab and unsure what I am doing wrong.

Below is my code. The first part (included for clarity) works fine.

```
to_plot = hu_atl;
mask = zeros(size(to_plot));

mask(hz_atl>200) = NaN;  %open ocean
mask(hz_atl<=200) = 1; %shelf

mask(mask==1) = to_plot(mask==1); %(or pick other suitable value)
log = log10(mask);
pcolor(log10(mask')); %plot h/u3 on a log scale

latlim = [-90 90]; %set the latitude limits
lonlim = [100 180]; %set the longitude limits

shading interp; %hide the grid lines, without this, the map just looks black due to all the grid lines

c = colorbar;
c.Label.String = 'log 10(h/u^3)'; %This labels the colourbar

caxis([0 6]); %This sets the upper and lower limits of the colourbar
```

Below is the colourbar code, which plots the figure below.

```
crange = [ 0 0.0001;0.0001 2.7;2.7 inf] ;
cmap = jet(size(crange,1)) ;
%%Arrange the colors range
colors = zeros(size(log));         
for i = 1:size(crange,1)
    colors(log > crange(i,1) & log<=crange(i,2)) = crange(i,2);           
end

colormap(cmap)

title('Global tidal mixing front positions based on TPXO9 tidal data')
xlabel('Longitude') 
ylabel('Latitude') 
set(gca,'XTick',[]) %hides tick numbers on x axis
set(gca,'YTick',[]) %hides tick numbers on y axis
```

Is there a way to change the ranges on the colourbar to match my requirements above?
Thanks in advance for any assistance!

[image]

Comment: First off, avoid using `log` as a variable name as there is already a built-in function with the same name, it will just get confusing and difficult to debug your code in case something breaks! Second, your colormap is probably already correct (didn't check). You probably just want to change the visible ticks of it, which you can do with `set(c, 'Ticks', [0, 0.001, 2.7])` or whatever you want!

Comment: Excellent point! I didn't think of that when I set the name. Thanks. And thanks for the help. I'll give it a go!